# Warning: Cannot modify header information (PHP)

Tags: php, header

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "ttps" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\login.php on line 6

Warning: file_get_contents(ttps://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=6628226&client_secret=Qw6Br6P61GMUttoD5xwE&redirect_uri=http://localhost/login.php&code=c606e8b66b49a7250e): failed to open stream: No error in D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\login.php on line 6

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\login.php:6) in D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\login.php on line 10
```

Помогите пожалуйста что не так вот код:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
if(empty($_GET['code'])){header("location:
/");}
else{
    $token = file_get_contents("ttps://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=".$appid."&client_secret=".$appkey."&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&code=".$_GET['code']);
    $token = json_decode($token, true);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token['access_token'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $token['user_id'];
    header('location: /');
}
?>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents("ttps://oauth` поменяйте на `file_get_contents("https://oauth` `tts` -> `https`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "ttps"

Ответ в сообщении об ошибке: `tts` на `https`

```
file_get_contents("ttps://oauth...");
```

поменяйте на

```
file_get_contents("https://oauth...");
```